# A speculative question about sensation

Tags: neuroscience, sensation, senses

I know this is rather speculative and I am not a biologist, but I have womdered about this for a long time.
I have always been able to pinpoint the central line of any part of my body exactly as if there were some nerve running through it. For example, given a pen, I could trace the line dividing one of my toes precisely. I, in some way, sense that the pencil is exactly at the middle?
 Is there any physiological reason for this? Is this true for everyone or is this an illusion peculiar to me?

Answer (score 1):

given a pen you can trace a line anywhere on your body. This is becasue humans have [Proprioception](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proprioception).  we can sense the movement of our muscles, tendons, and joints and track the location of every element of our body. Using this we can control our body precisely without other sensory input. It takes time to completely master this but most people have done so by the time they become adults.